# Jquery is not hitting. No error also showing

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

jQuery Ajax call not hitting Controller Action in my application. I dont know happening with the code Jquery is not hitting. No error also showing I am running on my localhost, I don't know if that is part of the problem, but outside of Sitecore, I have build ajax commands off of regular MVC applications with no issues.

This is my view

```
@model BusinessEntity.BEModel.AssessmentDetailViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Assessement_Mapping</title>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    
     <script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#Assessment_Id").change(function (event) {

                    alert("You have Selected  :: " + $(this).val());
                    var item = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("Assessement_Mapping_Data", "Detail")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $("#Assessment_Id").val() },
                    success: function (x) {
                        $.each(x, function (i, y) {
                          $("#UserID").append('$('#IsActive').prop('checked', true);');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert('Invalid operation, try again');
                    }
                });
            });

         })

    </script>

</head>

<body>

<h4>AssessmentDetailViewModel</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Assessement_Mapping">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
           @* <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Assessment_Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Assessment_Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Assessment_Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Assessment_Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Assessment_Id" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Assinfo,"Assessment_Id","Assessment_Name"))"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Assessment_Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
          
           @* <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="IsActive" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="IsActive" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="IsActive" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
           @*
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserID" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="UserID" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="UserID" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="UserName" class="control-label"></label>
              @*  <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />*@
                  
                    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Userinfo.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Userinfo[i].IsActive" />
                        <label asp-for="@Model.Userinfo[i]">@Model.Userinfo[i].UserName</label>
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Userinfo[i].UserID" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Userinfo[i].UserName" />
                    }
                <span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
           @* <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
           
           
          
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult Assessement_Mapping_Data(int id)
{
     List<AssessmentMapping> lst1 = obj.getallusers(id);
            AssessmentDetailViewModel productInfo = new AssessmentDetailViewModel();

            productInfo.Assmappinginfo = lst1;
            StringBuilder sd = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (AssessmentMapping item in lst1)
            {
                if (item.IsActive)
                {
                    sd.Append(sd.ToString());
                }
            }
            //ViewBag.Selecteduser = sd;

            return Json(productInfo);
}
```

This is My function

```
public List<AssessmentMapping> getallusers(int id)
{
    List<AssessmentMapping> lstobj = new List<AssessmentMapping>();
    lstobj=_context.AssessmentMappingData.Where(m=>m.Assessment_Id==id).ToList();
    return lstobj;
}
```

Comment: You should call your `Controller` method from the `AJAX` call: `@Url.Action("Assessement_Mapping_Data")`  and not your `getallusers` method.

Comment: Your code, as provided, has a (obvious) syntax error: `alert("hi");` in the middle of an object defintion.

Comment: After calling from this @Url.Action("Assessement_Mapping_Data")  still not hitting.

Comment: @BhartiSingh What is your `Controller` name? Your call should be: `@Url.Action("Assessement_Mapping_Data", "ControllerName")`. Also remove all the `alert` especially below the `dataType: 'json'` call. That would result in an error since it is invalid syntax

Comment: Still it's not hitting

Comment: @BhartiSingh Do you see any errors on the console (Open it using F12) and check for any errors there.

Comment: it showing unexcepted end of input

Comment: @BhartiSingh That means there is something wrong with your `Jquery` syntax. Can you remove all alert and then post your code by updating your question?

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 
        
        
        POST http://localhost:5048/@Url.Action(%22DetailAssessement_Mapping_Data%22) 404 (Not Found)

Comment: now showing this error

Comment: @BhartiSingh Can you please post your updated code in your question. Also remember that `Url.Action` can only be used in `.cshtml` files and not in `.js` file. If you will see the error, the URL suggest that `Url.Action` is not resolved by your `Ajax` call. It should be `url: '@Url.Action("Assessement_Mapping_Data", "ControllerName")'`

Comment: i updated the code. Now the issue is that after selecting the dropdown value it's not bringing the checkbox checked value from the database. Please see my jquery and function

Comment: @BhartiSingh You should send your current selected value via your `AJAX` call: `data: { id: item },` and then check in your `Controller` method if you are getting the correct value in your `id` variable.

Comment: I'm getting the correct id value in the correct but my this option code < $.each(x, function (i, y) {
                          $("#UserID").append('$('#IsActive').prop('checked', true);');
                        });> not checking the checkbox.

Comment: @BhartiSingh I think its a syntax error that you have. Try this: `$("#UserID").append('$("#IsActive").prop("checked", true)');`

Comment: Still its not checking the checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please tyr this ajax and controller method**

**ajax : **

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',  //Change POST to GET
        url: '@Url.Action("Assessement_Mapping_Data")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: $("#Assessment_Id").val() },
         success: function (x) {
             alert("hi");
        $.each(x, function (i, y) {
                alert("hi");
                $("#UserID").append('< option value = "' + y.Value + '" > ' + y.Text + ' < /option>');
        });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('Invalid operation, try again');
        }
    });
```

**Controller : **

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Assessement_Mapping_Data(int id)
    {
        List<AssessmentMapping> lst1 = obj.getallusers(id);
        AssessmentDetailViewModel productInfo = new AssessmentDetailViewModel();

        productInfo.Assmappinginfo = lst1;
        return Json(productInfo, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //add , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
    }
```

Comment: @Bharti Singh Please try this

Comment: i updated the code. Now the issue is that after selecting the dropdown value it's not bringing the checkbox checked value from the database. Please see my jquery and function.

Comment: @BhartiSingh I have a doubt. UserID is dropdown box or textbox?

Comment: UserId is for checkbox value id

Comment: Assessment_id for dropdown

Comment: @BhartiSingh step 1: Assessment_Id dropdown change evennt working? show this alert(You have Selected  :: " + $(this).val())?, step 2: ajax success: function(x) x value come?

Comment: yes it's coming

Comment: @BhartiSingh Please try : please disable $.each function and use this one (prop or attr) $("#UserID").prop('checked', true); or $("#UserID")..attr('checked', true); It working means we will check next step

Comment: GET http://localhost:5048/@Url.Action(%22Assessement_Mapping_Data%22,%20%22Detail%22)?id=3 404 (Not Found)             Showing this error

Comment: @BhartiSingh can you share error screenshot to this mahalingamelex@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("getallusers")',
        dataType: 'json',
                data: { id: $("#Assessment_Id").val() },
                **alert("hi");Remove this line **

        success: function (x) {
            $.each(x, function (i, y) {
                alert("hi");
                        $("#UserID").append('
                    < option value = "' + y.Value + '" > ' + y.Text + ' < 
/option>');
        });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('Invalid operation, try again');
        }
    });
```